# How to get raw string of an image from Bitmap in android?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap

I am making an app where people can take and upload photos. I currently have a `Bitmap` object that represents the photo, and I'd like to post this to a server.

Unfortunately, the server expects raw text of the jpg (like what you would see if you typed `cat /path/to/jpg` on linux).

How can I convert my `Bitmap` into a `String` of this kind?

Comment: I really don't think you want a `String` or "text" (because a JPEG is binary data, and converting it to a `String` will corrupt the file). Maybe it's just a language issue... Anyway, I think what you want is raw `byte`s. Either as a `byte[]` or through an `Input/OutputStream`. However, if you want to post (as in HTTP `POST`), encoding the bytes in Base64 encoding might make sense. It's just hard to tell. You already have two answers guessing. For better answers, update the question with more (precise) details (like: How do you talk to the server? What is the protocol?). :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that your server expects a Base64 encoded image string, not just the string from `cat /path/to/jpg`.

To get a Base64 string, you could use:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); // '100' is quality
byte[] byteArray = out.toByteArray();
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your Bitmap image referenced by `bitmapImage` -

```
Bitmap bitmapImage = //your code for getting Bitmap
```

Now create a `ByteOutputStream`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutptuStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteOutptuStream); 
byte[] byteArray = byteOutptuStream.toByteArray();
```

Then encode the image using Base64 encoding -

```
String imageAsString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

**Update:** If you want to skip the `Base64`encoding then you can use the either of code snippet -

```
String imageAsString2 = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8"); 
String imageAsString3 = new String(byteArray);
String imageAsString4 = new byteArray.toString();
```

Comment: there is overhead to Base64 encoding though - how would I do this for the raw image string?