# How can I transfer image new intent

Tags: java, android

This is my adapter and I save my image string type in Responsemodel class.

```java
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.myviewholder>
{

    List<ResponseModel> data;

    private final IOtobusSaatleriInterface iOtobusSaatleriInterface;

    Context context;
    
    public MyAdapter(List<ResponseModel> data, IOtobusSaatleriInterface iOtobusSaatleriInterface, Context context) {
        this.data = data;
        this.iOtobusSaatleriInterface = iOtobusSaatleriInterface;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlerowdesign,parent,false);
        return new myviewholder(view,iOtobusSaatleriInterface);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position) {
        holder.t1.setText(data.get(position).getName());
        holder.t2.setText(data.get(position).getDesig());
        Glide.with(holder.t1.getContext())
                .load("http://example.site/Gurpinar/images/" +data.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.img);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return null!=data?data.size():0;

    }

    class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView img;
        TextView t1,t2;
        
        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView, IOtobusSaatleriInterface iOtobusSaatleriInterface) {
            super(itemView);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            t1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
            t2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.t2);
            
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (iOtobusSaatleriInterface != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION);
                        iOtobusSaatleriInterface.onItemClick(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,deneme.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name",data.get(position).getName());
                        intent.putExtra("resim","http://example.site/Gurpinar/images/");
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and my new empty activity

```java
public class deneme extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_deneme);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");

        String goruntu = intent.getStringExtra("resim");

        String.valueOf(Glide.with(imageView).load(goruntu));

        textView.setText(name);


    }
}
```

And my new empty activity

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".deneme">


 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
     android:gravity="left"
     android:text="TextView"
     android:textColor="#494545"
     android:textSize="25sp"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is I can access name data but image cannot be displayed.
How can I access the selected photo? I take the photos in mysql database and with the url recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can pass the image as a Base64 in the Intent and create in the new Activity a Imagefile from this String.

Create as Base64 String:
[How to get raw string of an image from Bitmap in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881672/how-to-get-raw-string-of-an-image-from-bitmap-in-android/29881847)

Create the Imagefile again from the String:
[Create image file from raw string data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652292/create-image-file-from-raw-string-data)